# A reflexive Banach space is separable if and only if its dual is separable

Tags: functional-analysis

Royden has stated the above and proved it as follows :
Let $X$ be a Banach space. The preceding theorem tells us that if $X^*$ is separable so is $X$, irrespective of any reflexivity assumption. Now assume that $X$ is reflexive and separable. Thus $J(X) = X^{**} = (X^* )^*$ is separable since $J$ is an isometry.

My questions:

1. Why was $X$ assumed to be complete? We didn't need it anywhere in the proofs.
2. Doesn't simply the continuity of $J$ do the job? Isn't the continuous image of a separable space separable?

Edit : $J$ is the natural embedding of $X$ into $X^{**}$ given by $J(x)(f)=f(x)$.

Comment: what is your $J$?

Comment: @PinkPanther I have edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1: The dual of any normed space is a Banach space.  In particular $X^{**}$ is a Banach space, so if $X$ is reflexive, it is isometric to a Banach space and therefore must be a Banach space itself.  So we lose nothing by writing "Banach space" as a hypothesis of the theorem.

I suppose the theorem is also true for incomplete reflexive spaces: vacuously true, because no such spaces exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your observations are both correct. $X$ need not be complete and a continuous image of any separable topological space is separable.